# tank.log grows till consume all available space

Tags: load-testing, yandex, yandex-tank

I use yandex-tank to generate a load 1 post per 10 seconds during 24h. But yandex-tank  failed after about 16 hours of running, because tank.log consumed all the free space available. In my case it increased till 37Gb.

*My load.ini:*

```
[phantom]
address=192.168.254.201 ;Target's address
port=12224 ;target's port
rps_schedule=const(0.1, 24h) ;load scheme
connection_test=0
ssl=0
```

*My ammo.txt consists of 10 similar post requests:*

```
300
POST /api/< maybe confidential data>dimension1,dimension2,channel HTTP/1.1
Host: <confidential data>:12224
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 103
Connection: keep-alive

{ "dimension1":"dimension1_1", "dimension2":"dimension2_not_used", "channel":"channel_1", "value": 91}
```

The command line:

```
yandex-tank ammo.txt
```

It seems that space consumed by repeating records "Stats cache timestamps:", like

```
2016-12-28 04:52:21,033 [DEBUG] yandextank.plugins.Aggregator.plugin plugin.py:101  Stats cache timestamps:
[1482836903, 1482836904, ....]
```

in the beginning of the file, this record consists of 1 timestamps. But the last available "Stats cache timestamps:" contains 54212 timestamps!
Ther are more than 3 billions of timestamps in the file totally!

Is there a way to suppress/switch off this logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. I've [removed](https://github.com/yandex/yandex-tank/commit/02232a1c8e5fec97e2749f6a4c095c058ff61dee) these messages.